# Crash happening in SDK (iOS/aOS)

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

My team and I are launching a new version of SFMC SDK.
After launching SDK 3.1.0 version, we have recorded 106k times of flashbacks and errors all pointing to not enough memory (Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed).
Subsequent to upgrading the SDK to 3.1.1 version, we still experience 24k times of flashback within a week.

The attachments are the iOS/aOS crash log.

Is there anyone have any idea about it?

aOS Crash Log FYI

````
      at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
      at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.storage.db.m.g(SourceFile)
      at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c.a(SourceFile)
      at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c$a.a(SourceFile)
      at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run(SourceFile)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) ```


Super Thanks!

KR,
Andrew
````

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.